# Console logging comparator boolean in Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, console.log

Somehow I manage not to get a good answer to this by googling. Java dev here, new to Javascipt.

I have this code:

```
console.log('this.props.projectData.length: ' + this.props.projectData.length);
console.log('this.props.projectData.length >= 0 : ' + this.props.projectData.length >= 0);
```

output:

```
this.props.projectData.length: 107
false
```

So, first of all, why it doesn't log the String part of the second line and secondly, why is it false, as it's clearly true. The length is 107, hence it's larger than 0.

Answer (score 2):

> why is it false, as it's clearly true?

The issue here is just the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence). For simplicity, suppose we have this array...

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
```

... whose length is clearly > 0.

If we do:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log("length > 0: " + arr.length > 0)
```

We are in fact doing 2 things.

1. Calculating the sum `"length > 0: " + arr.length`
2. Then, comparing the result of that sum with `0`

Therefore, due to operator precedence, we're doing this:

```
("length > 0: " + arr.length) > 0
```

Let's prove it. First:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log("length > 0: " + arr.length)
```

We are adding a number to a string, and that gives us a string, `"length > 0: 3"`.

Then, we compare a string to a number:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log("length > 0: 3" > 0)
```

Which is the same of `NaN > 0`. And that, of course, is `false`.

**Solution**:

What you want is this:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log("length > 0: " + (arr.length > 0))
//grouping operator here ----^--------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
console.log('this.props.projectData.length: ', this.props.projectData.length);
console.log('this.props.projectData.length >= 0 : ', this.props.projectData.length >= 0);
```

Comment: Sorcery.. Thank you. WIll accept your answer as it's allowed in 10 minutes.

Comment: @SteveWaters: Surely operator precedence is a thing in Java, no? Would be good if the answer explained the issue though.

Comment: @rockstar, in Java it would work as:
System.out.println("projectData.length >= 0 : " + this.props.projectData.length >= 0);"

Comment: @SteveWaters: I'm not saying the languages must work the same. I'm just saying that I imagine operators have *some* rules of precedence that shouldn't be all that foreign to Java devs. It is a surprising result, no doubt, but should be pretty clear once the expressions are separated. Anyway, I still think that while this is a solution, it doesn't really give an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Just one change is there,

```
console.log('this.props.projectData.length >= 0 : ' + this.props.projectData.length);
```

You are checking the length here and it is becoming true .
But now it will work fine.

Comment: Wait, you just removed the comparison that he's asking about, so it's now the same as his first line.